# Query a subarray of documents

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a database of posts, whose objects contains array of comments.

```
{
    "_id" : "g-6892440-S-5949476530307559428",
    "title" : "something",
    "comments" : []
}
{
    "_id" : "g-6892440-S-5946310723729645572",
    "title" : "something again",
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "11",
            "text" : "aaa",            
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "22",
            "text" : "bbb",            
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get comments whose text is "aaa". I found this tutorial http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/, where is something similar. My query is:

```
db.posts.find({"comments.text": "aaa" }, {"_id" : 0 , "comments._id" : 1, "comments.text" : 1 })
```

Which returns

```
{
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : "g-6892440-S-5946310723729645572-5946311678785249280",
            "text" : "aaa"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : "g-6892440-S-5946310723729645572-5946311735404158977",
            "text" : "bbb"
        }
    ]
}
```

but I just want comment with text equals "aaa". I also tried to do index by command:

```
db.posts.ensureIndex( { "comments.text": 1 } )
```

but it did not help.

Second question is how to implement query in Spring MongoDB framework. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this:

```
db.posts.find({"comments.text": "aaa" }, {"_id" : 0 , "comments.$" : 1, "comments._id" : 1, "comments.text" : 1 })
```

of course there is another way to do that with aggregation:

```
db.posts.aggregate(
   { $project : { comments : "$comments" , _id : 0}},
   { $unwind : "$comments"}, 
   { $match : {"comments.text": "aaa" }}
).result
```

and for aggregation the spring could be: (from https://blog.42.nl/articles/aggregations-mongodb-spring-data/)

```
DBCollection posts...
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match", new BasicDBObject("comments.text", "aaa"));
DBObject unwind = new BasicDBObject("$unwind", "$comments");
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject( "_id", 0);
fields.put("comments", "$comments");
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject("$project", fields);
List pipeline = Arrays.asList(project, match, unwind);
AggregationOutput output = posts.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Comment: Thanks both work. But I dont understand what "comments.$" do exactly and why it is not written about it in official tutorial. Thanks

Comment: $ is positional operation, when you query **"comments.text": "aaa"**, mongo will find that your second array member of comments has "aaa' for text. mongo turn **$** to **1** (as index) and it will return **comments.1** and it means choose index of 1 from the array (it could be vary for other comments)

Comment: a good reference for update, but you can get same behavior in find query http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/

Comment: Ok, thanks. Now, I found out that command: db.posts.find({"comments.text": "aaa" }, {"_id" : 0 , "comments.$" : 1 ,  "comments._id" : 1, "comments.text" : 1}) returns all fields of comments not only _id and text. How can I obtain only two fields. Thanks.